# crossDomain JQUIEY - JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, jquery

HOLA estoy aprendiendo JAVASCRIPT y estoy haciendo un ejercicio en donde consumo la API de la página de STAR WARS sin embargo me sale este error y no se como resolverlo.

**He realizado mi ejercicio de las siguiente  forma:**

Un archivo .html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="clase28.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Un archivo .js

```
    const API_URL = 'https://swapi.co/api/'
const PEOPLE_URL = 'people/:id'


const opts = {crossDomain : true }

const onPeopleResponse = function (persona){
    console.log(`hola yo soy, ${persona.name}`)
}

function obtenerPersonaje (id){
    const url =`${API_URL} ${PEOPLE_URL.replace(':id',id)}`
    $.get(url,opts,onPeopleResponse)
}

obtenerPersonaje(1)
```

Comment: Podes probar ver el resultado de console.log(url) para verificar que esté construyendo correctamente la url del servicio.

Comment: Hola cjara muchas gracias por tu ayuda, ya ha funcionado, realmente no supe como funciono por que no le hice nada jaja.
Te agradezco mucho tu ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

podrias indicar desde que entorno estás intentanto realizar la llamada, a mi no me lanza el error de CrossDomain(lanza cuando la petición se realiza desde un servidor distinto y éste no soporta CORS).

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
            <title>
                Get Ajax
            </title>
            <script crossorigin="anonymous" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js">
            </script>
        </meta>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container text-center">
            <h1>
                Persona
            </h1>
            <div id="people">
            </div>
        </div>
        <script>
            (function(){

   let idPeople = prompt("Ingresar el id de persona");

   var apiUrl = 'https://swapi.co/api/people/'+idPeople +'/';

   const opts = {crossDomain : true }

   const onPeopleResponse = function (persona) { 
    let nombrePersonaHtml = document.querySelector('#people');
       nombrePersonaHtml.innerHTML = '<h2> Mi nombre es ' + persona.name +  '<h2>' 
      }

   $.get(apiUrl,opts, onPeopleResponse );

  }())
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hola muchas gracias. Estoy usando Visual Estudio Code. Ejecutandolo claro en google chrome

Comment: En todo caso podrias agregar en tú pregunta tú codigo completo en la opción de fragmento html/javascript para ver tener un panorama más amplio de lo que estás intentando hacer.

Comment: muchas gracias cjara, Ya he edita mi pregunta.